# Probability multiplication rule and Conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I know that P(A|B)= probability of A given that B has occurred and it can be expressed as P(A intersection B)÷ P(B)
I know about this in in single events but when we draw two things like here an urn contains 10 black and 5 white balls here we need to find probability of both balls drawn are black why conditional probability = probability of both balls drawn are black (by permutation method) ÷ probability of second event. ( conditional probability is 9/14) I want to know why it works

Answer (score 0):

Number of black balls in the urn = 10

Number of white balls in the urn = 5

(Total number of balls in the urn = 15)

Let $A$ and $B$ denote the events that the first ball drawn is black and the second ball drawn is black, respectively.

Obviously,

$P(A) = P(\mbox{First ball drawn is black}) = {10 \over 15} = {2 \over 3}$

Since there is no replacement,

$P( B | A) = P(\mbox{Black ball in second draw given that we draw a black ball in the first draw}).$

Thus, we see that

$P(B | A) = {9 \over 14}$.

Using the multiplicative law in probability, we find that

$P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B | A) = {2 \over 3} \times {9 \over 14} = {3 \over 7}$,

which is the required probability. $\blacksquare$

Comment: I just want to know why probability of A intersection B is Probability of A × conditional probability

Comment: Let us consider two cases..

Case I: You draw a ball from the urn and then put it back in the urn. In this case, the two events $A$ and $B$ defined in the problem are clearly independent of each other. When you put the ball back into the urn, it has 15 balls. 

$P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B) = {10 \over 15} \times {10 \over 15} = {4 \over 9}$.

Case II: When the ball is not back after first draw, second draw is DEPENDENT on the outcome of first draw. So, we have to use the multiplication law of probability with conditional probability.

$P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B | A) = {3 \over 7}$.